# Is there a way to get data from a PNG map to a GeoJSON

Tags: maps, geojson, gdal, shapefile, qgis

I have a map which was published in PNG format without its underlying data :
[Map produced by the French Gov](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haqc3.png)

I also have this GeoJson of every district in France.
[Visualisation of GeoJson file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrSXH.jpg)

I need a file that would contain the content of the map in a format I can exploit (Shapefile, GeoJSON, TIFF, etc.). To do that I need to select the districts that are in each of the tiles.

Do you have any idea of a solution that would allow to use the GeoJSON as an overlay over the image to select the districts to put in each category ?

I have tried to georeference the image but that's about as far as I have succeeded.

Thank you

Comment: If you were able to georeference this image, you did the hard part. What else do you need?

Comment: I want to flag each district that appears in orange on the PNG map on my geoJSON.
That way I can dispay the information in the PNG as a map and not as a PNG

Comment: Find the centroid of each GeoJSON feature and then start checking the color of the pixel in the raster image. If you hit white or orange, you know the result. If you hit black, start looking around. It is a horrible solution to a horrible problem.

Comment: After georeferncing you can rasterize your districts and for example calculate the median/mode of each one (ignore black&white). You can attach those results in the attributes of the geojson again.